# Split shipping cost by weight across items in cart

Tags: java, algorithm, business-logic

I have two items in the cart item 1= $70 and item 2= $100 and i also have the total shipping i can charge, which is $15. While accepting this order Im trying to split the $15 shipping between item1 and item2 in a weighted manner based on the price. What is the best algorithm to split this and what is the logic/calculation look like ?

Any thoughts helpful, thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know Java, but since you included no Java code, I'll just give pseudocode to how to do this:

```
a = 70 / (70 + 100)
b = 100 / (70 + 100)
```

This normalizes the two values, and then you can just multiply `a` and `b` with $15 to get the proper ratio. In this case, `a` is `0.41` and `b` is `0.59`

Then:

```
ratio_item_a = 15 * a
ratio_item_b = 15 * b
```

`ratio_item_a` is `6.18` and `ratio_item_b` is `8.82`